# JODA time wrong values on each iteration

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

i am trying Joda time in java using the latest version 2.2 i have written a small snippet here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    BoilerTester clazz = new BoilerTester();
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar born  = Calendar.getInstance();
    //when returns 0 is 10363 when returning 1 = 10362 just a millisecond what have to do with days??
    System.out.println(Math.abs(today.getTimeInMillis()-born.getTimeInMillis()));
    born.set(1984,10,20);        
    clazz.compute(born,today);
}   
private void compute(Calendar born, Calendar today)
{
    System.out.println("JODA:  " + org.joda.time.Days.daysBetween(new org.joda.time.DateTime(born.getTime()),new org.joda.time.DateTime(today.getTime())).getDays());    
}
```

when i run the source code i am getting this values

> JODA:  10363

later I run the same code and I am getting

> JODA:  10362

Yes i have run maybe 2 or 3 times the same code to get different values but why this???

thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you ran it yesterday and today?

Comment: not one after the other immediately.. i have recorded a video as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that sometimes, the `today` and `born` dates are on the exact same millisecond, and sometimes they differ by a few milliseconds (the time that elapses between the first call to `Calendar.getInstance()` and the second one). Since getDays() returns the number of complete days, a few milliseconds could make a difference.

Comment: i have born.clear() and i now i see the right results but those time differs just a milliseconds what have to do with days??

Comment: Let's say you initialize `today`, and the number of millis after midnight is 2000. Let's say one millisecond elapses and then you initialize `born` (which has thus 2001 milliseconds after midniht). Now you set `born` to 1984/10/20. You thus compute the difference in complete days between 1984/10/20 and 2001 milliseconds and 2013/04/05 and 2000 milliseconds. And you thus have 10363 days minus 1 millisecond, and not 10363 days. Since getDays() returns the number of complete days, it truncates it to 10362 days.

Comment: but i am testing this code in the same day absolutely the same day :(

Comment: But not the same millisecond :-). You can avoid this kind of problems using 'Partial' in Joda-Time (check my answer)

Answer (score 1):

I was writing my answer but JB Nizet was faster (he is absolutely right on what is happening). If you want to get rid of this kind of problems, you should leverage the concept of [partial](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_partial.html) in joda-time:

*A partial in Joda-Time is a partial date and time representation. All implementations represent local dates and times, and do not reference a time zone. As such, they only partially represent a date or time in the datetime continuum.*

For example, with a [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html):

```
LocalDate born = new LocalDate(1984, 11, 20); // BE CAREFUL!: months in JDK are 0-11, but in Joda-Time are 1-12
System.out.println(Days.daysBetween(born, LocalDate.now()).getDays());
```

With this "partial" representation, you are not using hours, minutes, seconds or milliseconds internally, so you cannot face this problem due to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You're running a mix of JDK and Joda -- don't do that -- Joda replaces the JDK time classes **completely**.

Comment: Because it's not an answer? Should have been a comment to the original question.

Comment: I didn't downvote. The question mark in my statement should indicate that I was making a guess to the reason.